# How to turn a tuple into an integer in Python (examples inside)?

Tags: python, integer, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

"(1,2,3), (2,3,1)..."

I would like to change this into a list of integers:

"123, 231..."

How might I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait. Are those elements in tuples digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more functional approach:

```
[reduce(lambda a, x: a * 10 + x, t) for t in tuples]
```

**edit:**

Just for fun, a little benchmark against JBernardo's answer:

```
In [21]: %timeit [int(''.join(str(i) for i in t)) for t in tuples]
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.54 us per loop

In [22]: %timeit [reduce(lambda a, x: a * 10 + x, t) for t in tuples]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 us per loop
```

**edit 2:**

Akavall pointed out my original answer only works when the tuples have exclusively single digit integers.

If this is unacceptable for your use case, JBernardo's answer is probably a simpler way to do this. But just for fun:

```
[reduce(lambda a, x: a * 10**(len(str(x))) + x, t) for t in tuples]
```

or without any string conversions at all:

```
from math import log10
[reduce(lambda a, x: a * 10**(int(log10(x))+1) + x, t) for t in tuples]
```

Comment: Executes 6 microseconds faster, but takes decaseconds to figure out how the hell `reduce()` works when you come back to it in a few months.

Comment: Fair enough. You could also say it executes 5x faster. I'm sorry you find `reduce()` confusing; I personally find it far more straightforward than doing all that casting.

Comment: Your solution only works if tuples are made of single digit integers. What if `tuples = ((1,29,3), (2,3,1))` ?

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
[int(''.join(str(i) for i in t)) for t in tuples]
```

Answer (score 1):

Less complex than @Luke's

```
[sum(x * 10**i for i, x in enumerate(t[1][::-1])) for t in tuples]
```

It just sum like x1 + x2 * 10^2 + ... + xN * 10^n

`[::-1]` - to reverse the tuple, enumerate to get (xN, N) pairs.